# How to get preproc for BERT

Tags: python, keras

I am using the stackoverflow tab classification csv dataset, which I have loaded into a dataframe:

```
X = df.post
y = df.tags
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state = 42)
```

In addition to some other classification models, I would also like to run BERT, however, it requires a variable preproc. I am unsure which function will get that:

```
import ktrain
from ktrain import text
model = text.text_classifier('bert', (x_train, y_train), preproc=preproc)
learner = ktrain.get_learner(model,train_data=(x_train, y_train), val_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=6)
```

In some documentation I see people use text.texts_from_folder(), but I have everything in a dataframe already. Is there another function in text. that woud help me get preproc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the *ktrain* [text classification tutorial](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial-04-text-classification.ipynb) for a full list of available preprocessing functions.  For instance, in your case, you can either use `texts_from_df` or `texts_from_array`. These functions will preprocess the text documents in the way expected by the model. See [this example notebook](https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/examples/text/ArabicHotelReviews-BERT.ipynb) for an example of using `texts_from_df`.  Alternatively, you can use the [Transformer API](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial-A3-hugging_face_transformers.ipynb) in *ktrain*.

Answer (score 0):

I have not find too, so i wrote a function that splits csv into txt files:

```
import time
import os
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

treads=12
path = os.getcwd()
train_path = path + '/' + 'train_df' + '/'
test_path = path + '/' + 'test_df' + '/'

train_len = range(len(train_df['text']))
texts = train_df['text'].tolist()
ids = train_df['id'].tolist()
classes= train_df['class'].tolist()

def create_directory(directory):
    try:
        os.mkdir(directory)
    except OSError:
        print('OSError')
    else:
        print('Error')

def write_txt(text_, id_, class_, path, i):
    cur_path = path + '/' + str(id_) + '/'
    create_directory(cur_path)
    with open(cur_path + f'{class_}_{i}.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(text_)

Parallel(n_jobs=treads)(delayed(write_txt)(texts[i], ids[i], classes[i], path, i) for i in tqdm(train_len))
```